# Image map coordinates for different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, imagemap

I am trying to create an image map, where I define on the images coordinates that are links to the some other pages. Now the problem I am facing is that the position of coordinates is not relative.

If the image is on a different browser or in a different screen size, then the coordinates are not preserved. I mean a link which was at a particular place in the image is now on some other place of image.

Can anyone provide a piece of code where I can have some relative positioning where even the browser size or the image size will change the coordinates position also with it.

I tried to user percentage tags like COORDSCALE "50%,50%" but it seems like a wrong attribute for the Area tag. Even this COORDSCALE="ABSOLUTE|RELATIVE" is also not working.

First of all, are these the right attributes? Is there a possibility of relative positioning? Any CSS, or Javascript code will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the image with div that has relative position. Inside it use absolutely positioned elements to imitate the same thing imagemap is supposed to do.

Google "CSS image map" to find more information about the technique.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me give it a try to that. Will be back with more Issues. :) :)